# Is it possible to edit the Facebook lookback video?

Tags: facebook, facebook-lookback

Can you edit the Facebook "looking  back" video, swapping some pictures?

Trying to change some photos, does anyone get a prompt to do that anywhere?

Comment: It is hard to know what you mean by your second question. Could you rewrite it?

Answer (score 2):

[Lookback](https://www.facebook.com/lookback) now features an edit button, or just head over to [Edit Lookback](https://www.facebook.com/lookback/edit/).

Select your moments, and choose update